# click event on jqueryui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm starting with jQuery and Jquery UI. Currently I have a problem with a modal dialog I've opened that contains elements from an ajax iTunes response:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $url,
    dataType: 'JSONP'
}) 
.done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  var cuadro_itunes = "<table><tr><td>Artista</td><td>Tema</td><td>Portada</td><td>Usar</td></tr>";
  $.each(data.results, function(i) {
    cuadro_itunes = cuadro_itunes+"<tr><td>"+
      data.results[i].artistName+"</td><td>"+
      data.results[i].trackName+"</td><td>"+
      "<img class='itunes-imagen' id='"+i+"' src='"+data.results[i].artworkUrl100+"' />"+
      "<input type='hidden' class='itunes-url' id='"+i+"' value='"+data.results[i].trackViewUrl+"' /></td><td>"+
      "<input type='button' class='itunes-select' id='"+i+"' value='Seleccionar' /></td></tr>";
  });
  cuadro_itunes = cuadro_itunes+"</table>";

  $("#itunes-dialog").html( cuadro_itunes );
  $("#itunes-dialog").dialog("open");
})
.fail(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

The point is that each row element has a input button tag. Now I want to catch whenever the input button is clicked to pass the selected values to the parent window:

```
$(".itunes-select").on("click", function() {
    $("#itunes-dialog").dialog("close");
    $("body").find(".enlace#"+window.busqueda_id).val( $("#itunes-dialog").find(".itunes-url#"+$(this).attr("id")).val() );
    $("body").find(".portada#"+window.busqueda_id).val( $("#itunes-dialog").find(".itunes-imagen#"+$(this).attr("id")).val() );
  });
```

But the click event is never triggered. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are your ids repeated across the document?

Comment: Unrelated to the question: I'd recommend you don't concatenate variables to text literals to compose HTML. Data in those variables could potentially have special characters that will break your layout or even pose security risks (depending on the source). Either use jquery's `.text()` or html-encode each value during concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the

```
$(".itunes-select").on("click", function() {
    $("#itunes-dialog").dialog("close");
    $("body").find(".enlace#"+window.busqueda_id).val( $("#itunes-dialog").find(".itunes-url#"+$(this).attr("id")).val() );
    $("body").find(".portada#"+window.busqueda_id).val( $("#itunes-dialog").find(".itunes-imagen#"+$(this).attr("id")).val() );
  });
```

part inside the ajax success function (after the $.each() part), and this should work. If doing this way, you bind the click event to dynamic generated content.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this ?

```
$(document).on("click" , ".itunes-select" , function () {

    // Your Code Here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `$(document).on("click", ".itunes-select", function(){});`.

The way you're attaching that click relates to then selected elements. From jQuery docs: "The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object."